# Is lower chest isolation necessary?

Tags: bodybuilding, bench-press, chest

As a beginner, like a lot of beginners, I did way too much volume. Eventually, I went in the complete other direction and currently use a high intensity, low volume regime. I now do 6 working sets per workout, and with my split average 10-12 set per week for chest. That 6 set usually comprises of 2 sets flat bench, 2 sets of an incline press or hammer press type machine for upper chest and fly movement, usually pec deck. I consider myself a powerbuilder, I want to get bigger, but I also love achieving new PR's so my goal is to balance hypertrophy with strength increase. What I want to know is, in terms of the bodybuilding goals, is targeting the lower chest necessary. Is the flat bench enough or do I need a decline press/lower chest fly movement too?